# dockerode imperative cli equivalent

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, dockerode

I am attempting to compile & execute a java program within a dockerode container in my node app. I am able to do this by first writing to a `tmp.java` file using basic javascript and then running the following shell commands:

`docker run --rm -v $PWD:/app -w /app java:8 javac tmp.java`

`docker run --rm -v $PWD:/app -w /app java:8 java tmp`

However, I am now trying to transition to using the dockerode module and am attempting to replicate this functionality as follows (based on the example on the dockerode github):

```
docker.run(
  'java:8',
  ['javac', 'tmp.java'],
  {
    Volumes: {
      '/': {}
    },
    WorkingDir: '/'
  },
  process.stdout
)
.then(data => {
  var output = data[0]
  console.log('OUTPUT: ', output)

  var container = data[1]
  console.log(output.StatusCode)
  return container.remove()
})
```

However, this produces no output and does not generate `tmp.class` as expected when I specify `Volumes` and `WorkingDir` options, and when I leave out those options, I get the error: `javac: file not found: tmp.java` which I assume means my volume is not mounting correctly. 
Essentially, I am trying to create a temporary microcontainer, compile & run my java program in the container, and then destroy the container. Thus, I am unable to install a JDK and compile the program locally on my host system and have to essentially work exclusively within the container.

I am currently trying to use imperative Docker commands to achieve this use-case and am able to accomplish this using the cli commands above, however, I am unable to do the same thing using `dockerode` for node (whether through imperative commands or using a dockerfile).

I would really appreciate any help with this!

Comment: I'd be very surprised to see a `javac` command produce a PNG file as its output.  Is that actually the result you're getting, or are you getting some kind of text output or an exception?

Comment: My first instinct reading through the question would be to install a JDK on the host and run the local `javac` command, instead of trying to run it via Docker; my second would be to run it in a Dockerfile instead of via imperative `docker run` commands.  I think your Node code is mounting an anonymous volume on `/app` instead of bind-mounting the host directory.

Comment: @DavidMaze I updated my question with some more details, let me know if I can clarify anything else. I see your point with regards to running `javac` locally, the problem is I am not sure installing a JDK on the host is a viable option for my use case given that I am essentially trying to handle the code execution completely remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your directory is not mapped.

This options object is the equivalent of the options `--rm -v $PWD:/app -w /app`

```
  {
    HostConfig: {
      AutoRemove: true,
      Binds: [
          `${process.cwd()}:/app`
      ]
    },
    WorkingDir: '/app'
  }
```

- `AutoRemove: true` is `--rm`
- `` Binds: [ `${process.cwd()}:/app` ] `` is `-v $PWD:/app`, with `process.cwd()` as `$PWD`
- `WorkingDir: '/app'` is `-w /app`

I also had to change the order of the arguments, as I was getting `TypeError: dest.on is not a function`. Running `dockerode@3.1.0` I had to set the output stream as the 3rd argument and the option object as the 4th argument.

So the full command looked like this:

```
docker.run(
  'java:8',
  ['javac', 'tmp.java'],
  process.stdout,
  {
    HostConfig: {
      AutoRemove: true,
      Binds: [
          `${process.cwd()}:/app`
      ]
    },
    WorkingDir: '/app'
  }
)
```